# Windows 7 performance compared to XP

Tags: windows-7

I'm thinking of upgrading to Windows 7, having missed Vista (well, "missing" is not really the word :-), so I was wondering, how do you think Windows 7 will run on something like this: [HP 6715s](http://www.cdfreaks.com/hardware/product/28151-HP-6715s.html), compared to XP?

I know what the official recommendations says, but I'm just looking for someone's opinion, if he tried it on something similar, hardware-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 is pretty snappy. There are still a few aspects that slow it down in the every day use but compared to Windows XP & Vista, it does pretty well.

Comment: I absolutely agree. 

I did not expect a snappy OS, but my 4 year old Thinkpad runs it seemlessly. Despite being a Mac fan (I admit) Windows 7 really has me for the PC.

Comment: @Kriem - Well, that's excellent news. I was worried about memory requirement, but if what you say is true, it is certanly a relief on my budget.

Answer (score 6):

I have upgraded my pc, an Intel Core2Duo 6600, now 2 years old, from XP to Windows 7 RC.
So far my performance experience has been excellent. I find that good ol' explorer responds faster. The cold-boot time (power-on to desktop) has shortened measurably. In my opinion Windows 7, for day-to-day use, is as fast if not faster that XP, running on the same hardware.

You can find any number of performance comparisons: here's one by [ZDnet](http://blogs.zdnet.com/hardware/?p=3789)

Comment: @Edoode - thank you for the link. I won't re-accept your answer, since it wouldn't be fair to Sam152, but at least let me help you with a few rep points :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to a recent CNet article ([Benchmarked: Windows 7 RTM versus Vista and XP](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/software/0,39029471,49303187,00.htm)):

> "Windows 7 performs better than Vista and is also faster than XP, although XP remains more capable for devices with limited memory and outdated graphics..."